# Code not running properly

Tags: python

The code I have below is supposed to run the number of words that start with a certain letter, but when I run it, the counts are all 0, instead of what they should be: {'I': 2, 'b': 2, 't': 3, 'f': 1}. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
def initialLets(keyStr):
        '''Return a dictionary in which each key is the initial letter of a word in t and the value is the number of words that begin with that letter. Upper
        and lower case letters should be considered different letters.'''
        inLets = {}
        strList = keyStr.split()
        firstLets = []
        for words in strList:
            if words[0] not in firstLets:
                firstLets.append(words[0])
        for lets in firstLets:
            inLets[lets] = strList.count(lets)
        return inLets

text = "I'm born to trouble I'm born to fate"
print(initialLets(text))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
text = "I'm born to trouble I'm born to fate"
new_text = text.split()
final_counts = {i[0]:sum(b.startswith(i[0]) for b in new_text) for i in new_text}
```

Output:

```
{'I': 2, 'b': 2, 't': 3, 'f': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a counter as you append the letter but not its number of occurrences.

So to simplify:

```
def initialLets(keyStr):
        '''Return a dictionary in which each key is the initial letter of a word in t and the value is the number of words that begin with that letter. Upper
        and lower case letters should be considered different letters.'''

        strList = keyStr.split()

        # We initiate the variable that gonna take our results
        result = {}

        for words in strList:
            if words[0] not in result:
                # if first letter not in result then we add it to result with counter = 1
                result[words[0]] = 1
            else:
                # We increase the number of occurence
                result[words[0]] += 1

        return result

text = "I'm born to trouble I'm born to fate"
print(initialLets(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are checking if the first letter of the word is in the list before putting it in. That would just make the list comprise of only 1 of each letter. Secondly, your `strList` is a list of each word, instead of `inLets[lets] = strList.count(lets)`, it should be `inLets[lets] = firstLets.count(lets)`... While your current code isn't the cleanest way to do it, this minor modification would have worked.

```
def initialLets(keyStr):
    '''Return a dictionary in which each key is the initial letter of a word in t and the value is the number of words that begin with that letter. Upper
    and lower case letters should be considered different letters.'''
    inLets = {}
    strList = keyStr.split()
    firstLets = []
    for words in strList:
        firstLets.append(words[0])
    for lets in firstLets:
        inLets[lets] = firstLets.count(lets)
    return inLets

text = "I'm born to trouble I'm born to fate"
print(initialLets(text))
```